# Batch insert codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just want to ask on what am I doing wrong in the insert batch here is my controller

```
            $ctr = count($this->input->post('txt_equipb'));

            for($i = 0; $i < $ctr; $i++){
                $data2s[] = array('EquipmentName' => $this->input->post('txt_equipb')[$i],
                            'EquipmentType' => $this->input->post('txt_equiptype')[$i],
                            'RequirementID' => $id2);
            }

            $cmd2 = $this->Software_model->add_equip($data2s);
```

MODEL

```
    public function add_equip($data2s)
    {
        foreach($data2s as $d){
            $data2[] = array('EquipmentName' => $d['EquipmentName'],
            'EquipmentType' => $d['EquipmentType'],
            'RequirementID' => $d['RequirementID']);
    }

         return $this->db->insert_batch('equipment', $data2);
    }
```

the problem is it is inserting  only the first batch of insert but the rest doesnt save on the database

EDITED

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["EquipmentName"]=> string(7) "Brand G" 
["EquipmentType"]=> string(19) "Measuring equipment" ["RequirementID"]=> 
string(2) "45" } }
```

i got this following result it only captures the first input I do i wonder why the naming I use for the textbox is txt_equipb[]

EDITED
VIEW:

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1" id="first">
            <label>Equipment Brand</label>    
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" id="firstbtn" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                </span>

                    <input class="form-control target" id="eb" name="txt_equipb[]" placeholder="Enter Equipment Brand" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter the Equipment Brand.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>

            </div>                
        </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1" id="third">
            <label>Equipment Type</label>    
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" id="thirdbtn" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                </span>

                <input class="form-control" id="type" name="txt_equiptype[]" placeholder="Enter Equipment Type" required />

            </div>   
        </div>
```

here is the format I used for naming in views.

Comment: What result do you get when you try : `var_dump($data2s)` ?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["EquipmentName"]=> string(7) "Brand G" ["EquipmentType"]=> string(19) "Measuring equipment" ["RequirementID"]=> string(2) "45" } } i got this following result it only captures the first input I do i wonder why the naming I use for the textbox is txt_equipb[]

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#firstbtn').click(function(){
                $('#eb').clone().appendTo('#first');
            }); i also add this jquery to duplicate the text box every time a button is clicked if this info helps

Comment: print out your post array because it looks like you do have only one item in your array- if not post the content of your post array - but pls do it by editing your question and adding this information - instead of spamming the comment box

Comment: Hi @CedrixCedrix, could you also provide the `txt_equipb[]` input form html code?

Comment: sure will do wait

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this hope it will help you

```
  $ctr = count($this->input->post('txt_equipb'));
  $data2s = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < $ctr; $i++){
            $data2s[$i] = array('EquipmentName' => $this->input->post('txt_equipb'),
                        'EquipmentType' => $this->input->post('txt_equiptype'),
                        'RequirementID' => $id2);
        }

        $cmd2 = $this->Software_model->add_equip($data2s);
```

MODEL

```
 public function add_equip($data2s)
{
     return $this->db->insert_batch('equipment', $data2);
}
```

Comment: now it returns a error of array to string convertion

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will give you an idea

```
  public function yourfunctionname()
{

$EquipmentName = $this->input->post('txt_quipb');
$EquipmentType = $this->input->post('EquipmentType');

$value = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($EquipmentName); $i++)
{
  $value[$i] = array(

    'EquipmentName' =>  $EquipmentName[$i],
    'EquipmentType' =>  $EquipmentType[$i],
    'RequirementID' => $id
  );
}

$this->db->insert_batch('table_name',$value);

redirect(base_url('url'));
exit();
}
```

Comment: thanks please vote my answer so that it will help to others

Comment: still the same it only returns one array

Comment: have you put in your html tags an array? example <input type="text" name="txt_quipb[]" value="">